# INSTEAD OF UPDATE, is it possible to update columns without listing them out?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, database-trigger

I have created a trigger, and I want it to perform a function on the value of a column if that column is updated, otherwise I just want to update normally. And to make the DB easier to maintain, I don't want to list out the columns to update, because I don't want to update the trigger whenever I add/remove a column to the table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER modify_country_code
ON Location
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    IF UPDATE(CountryCode)
        BEGIN

            -- This works if I am only updating the CountryCode column. But if updating
            -- multiple columns, the other columns are not updated (obviously)
            UPDATE Location
            SET Location.CountryCode = dbo.MyFunction(inserted.CountryCode)
            FROM inserted
            WHERE Location.Id = inserted.Id

        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Location
            -- possible to perform an update without listing the columns?
        END

END
```

Comment: In brief: **NO** - the `UPDATE` statement in T-SQL **must have** all columns explicitly listed that you wish to update to a new value

Comment: @marc_s I see. Maybe it will be easier to use an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger then, although I can't modify the Recursive Trigger settings, so I guess I'd need to add some checks to prevent recursion. Thanks